# Bcrypt Not Saving? - PassportJS

Tags: node.js, express, hash, passport.js, bcrypt

For some reason the code below does not save to the database? Can anyone tell me why this will not work to save a user's new password using PassportJS?

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;
  var SALT_FACTOR = 5;

  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

  bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Seems to me you ought to have `user.save()` after `user.password = hash;`

Comment: Could you show me how that would look?